How to align the colors of contours and legend bar in ContourPlot
Consider the following plot:
r1f[x_, y_] = 0.001/y x^-3
ContourPlot[r1f[x, y], {x, 0.211, 0.95}, {y, 0.01, 20}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], ImageSize -> Large, 
 ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
 Contours -> 
  Log[{0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[18, Black], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.211, 0.95}, {0.01, 20}, {10^-5., 6.}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[{Automatic, {10^-5, 6}}, {0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 
    0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}], FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)"}], 20, Thick, 
   Black], ColorFunctionScaling -> True]

The legend colors are not adjusted with the contour colors. I naively expected that specifying ColorFunction -> Automatic and BarLegend[{Automatic, would do this aligning, but something weird happens.
Is there any way to align them without manually adjusting colors to the legend bar while preserving the legend labels and the same color scheme (this is default in 13.2)? 
Update. Slight change of the styling:
r1f[x_, y_] = 0.001/y x^-3
form[x_] := 
 ReplaceAll[x, {NumberForm[y_, {w_, z_}] :> ScientificForm[y, 2]}]
ContourPlot[r1f[x, y], {x, 0.211, 0.95}, {y, 0.01, 20}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], ImageSize -> Large, 
 ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
 Contours -> 
  Log[{0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}], 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[18, Black], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.211, 0.95}, {0.01, 20}, {10^-5., 6.}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {10^-5, 6}}, {0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 
     0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 13], 
    LegendFunction -> form, LegendMarkerSize -> 500, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Placed["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)", Right]], Below], 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log", "Log"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)"}], 20, Thick, 
   Black]]

Update
An ugly approach would be the following. Let us define this initial ContourPlot as pt. Then, I may access its internal structure: colors = Drop[pt[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]], 1][[All, 2]]. Then use these colors instead of Automatic in PlotLegends ->  BarLegend[{Automatic. So,
marks = {0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1, 5};
colors = Drop[pt[[1]][[1]][[1]][[2]][[1]], 1][[All, 2]];
pt1 = ContourPlot[r1f[x, y], {x, 0.211, 0.95}, {y, 0.01, 20}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 18], PlotPoints -> 200, 
  ImageSize -> Large, ColorFunction -> Automatic, 
  Contours -> Log[marks], LabelStyle -> Directive[18, Black], 
  PlotRange -> {{0.211, 0.95}, {0.01, 20}, {10^-5., 6.}}, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[BarLegend[{colors, {10^-5, 6}}, marks, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 13], 
     LegendFunction -> form, LegendMarkerSize -> 500, 
     LegendLabel -> 
      Placed["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)", Right]], Below], 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log", "Log"}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[Row[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(1\)]\)"}], 20, Thick, 
    Black]]


But the approach is dumb - it requires computing the contour plot twice.

In your 1st bit of code change {Automatic, {10^-5, 6}} in BarLegend to just Automatic.  You are over specifying and getting it wrong.

You also do not need options ColorFunctionScaling as its default is True. Nor do you need PlotRange as you are not plotting a range that differs from the x and y ranges you provided and Mma works out the function range for you.  If you had issues you could go with PlotRange->Full or PlotRange->All.
